# Move a Web Site project with a web service to AWS windows server

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web-services, amazon-web-services

I've started ut a new instance of a windows server 2008 and am trying to move and launch my web service I've created in Visual Studio. How do I move the project from my local computer to the remote desktop? Grateful for all help!

I've tried the really simple approach and just copied the directory to the remote desktop in the same location as on my local computer. Did not work.. When I try to access the same adress that it has on my local computer (http://localhost:80/somesite all I get is this:

HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden

The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.

I'm probably going about this the wrong way, but don't know where to start..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to setup IIS. See the following link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28693/Deploying-ASP-NET-Websites-on-IIS-7-0

Answer (score 1):

I would make sure asp.net is enabled in the IIS server. Also try to explicitly hit your page such as:

```
http://localhost:80/somesite/myhome.aspx
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there is a quick answer to your particular issue, but if you're going to be doing this sort of thing often, it is best to take some time up front and read up, then click around and get a feel for IIS.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178477.aspx

Visual Studio has abstracted much of the site/virtual directory setup and configuration, chances are you can't just copy the files over and have it work.  There are lots of things to think about:  websites versus virtual directories and their configurations, application pools and their identities, file permissions, default documents, etc.  enjoy.